# Building Ada Web Server fails

Tags: ada, gnat, gprinstall

I am trying to build the AWS GPL 2015, but I get this error:

```
$ make setup build
gprbind xoscons.bexch
gnatbind xoscons.ali
gnatgcc -c b__xoscons.adb
gnatgcc xoscons.o -o xoscons
Setup OS specific definitions
Can not generate system tags. The test are disabled
aws.gpr:76:04: package "install" is forbidden in aggregate projects
gprbuild: "tools/tools.gpr" processing failed
makefile:183: recipe for target 'build-native' failed
make: *** [build-native] Error 4
```

I am using this GNAT:

```
$ gnat --version
GNAT 4.9.2
Copyright 1996-2014, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of AWS requires 'gprinstall', so you should compile with GNAT GPL 2015 to get all the needed tools.